# React/JS Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, uncaught-exception

I have just started learning JS/react and I got an error from a html file complaining as "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined". Please see below as an example.
[image]

The error is coming from the line 8

> ```
>     const electron = require('electron');
> ```

from the following code

```
this is addWindow.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Add shopping list item</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    const electron = require('electron');
    const {ipcRenderer} = electron;

    const form = document.querySelector('form');
    form.addEventListener('submit', submitForm);

    function submitForm(){
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  </script>
  <form> 
    <div>
      <label>Enter Item</label>
      <input type="text" id="item" autofocus>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">add item</button>
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

I have researched and noticed a lot of other people are having the issue so I added

> ```
>   nodeIntegration: true,
> ```

```
this is main.js
const electron = require("electron");
const url = require("url");
const path = require("path");

const { app, BrowserWindow, Menu } = electron;

let mainWindow;
let addWindow;

//listen
app.on("ready", function () {
  //create new window
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      preload: `${__dirname}/preload.js`,
    },
  });

  //
  mainWindow.loadURL(
    url.format({
      pathname: path.join(__dirname, "mainWindow.html"),
      protocol: "file:",
      slashes: true,
    })
  );
  //Quit app when closed
  mainWindow.on("closed", function () {
    app.quit();
  });

  //build menu from template
  const mainMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(mainMenuTemplate);
  //insert menu
  Menu.setApplicationMenu(mainMenu);
});

//handle add window
function createAddWindow() {
  //create new window
  addWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 300,
    height: 200,
    title: "Add shopping list item",
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      preload: `${__dirname}/preload.js`,
    },
  });

  //
  addWindow.loadURL(
    url.format({
      pathname: path.join(__dirname, "addWindow.html"),
      protocol: "file:",
      slashes: true,
    })
  );

  //garbage collection
  addWindow.on("close", function () {
    addWindow = null;
  });
}

//add clear quit

//create menu template
const mainMenuTemplate = [
  {
    label: "la",
  },
  {
    label: "File",
    submenu: [
      {
        label: "Add Item",
        accelerator: process.platform == "darwin" ? "Command+A" : "Ctrl+A", //mac for darwin
        click() {
          createAddWindow();
        },
      },
      {
        label: "Clear Item",
      },
      {
        label: "Quit",
        accelerator: process.platform == "darwin" ? "Command+Q" : "Ctrl+Q", //mac for darwin
        click() {
          app.quit(); //control Q
        },
      },
    ],
  },
];

if (process.platform == "darwin") {
  // mainMenuTemplate.unshift({});
}

// add dev tool item if not in prod
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
  mainMenuTemplate.push({
    label: "Developer Tools",
    submenu: [
      {
        label: "Toggle DevTools",
        accelerator: process.platform == "darwin" ? "Command+I" : "Ctrl+I",
        click(item, focusedWindow) {
          focusedWindow.toggleDevTools();
        },
      },
      {
        role: "reload",
      },
    ],
  });
}
```

But I still have no luck. Could you please help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you used `babel` to transcompile before deploy your project?

Comment: The code cannot be used directly by the browser. This is typical when writing react code. You have to use a build process to produce a bundle that the javascript engine in the web browser can use. If you are learning react, you should use [https://create-react-app.dev/](https://create-react-app.dev/) or a similar library where the build tools (webpack, babel etc.) are included.

Comment: Specifically your error message is telling you that `require()` does not exist in a web browser. `require()` is something that can be used in javascript running on node.js on a server. In client side code (running in the browser, which is what you want here) you have to transpile the code using build tools such as babel and / or webpack which will process the source code into something that can be run in the browser. Your small code will be bundled together with the requirements into a big javascript file that includes both the react runtime and your application code.

Comment: @Navand I have babel installed on visual code

Comment: @HåkenLid I did call "create-react-app shopping_list" and ported over all the files to the new shopping_list and I still see the same error :( I am not sure how to bundle things together.

Comment: What do you mean "ported over all the files"? You should read the create-react-app docs. The commands are `npm start` to run a dev server and `npm build` to make a production bundle. There's no "ported over all the files" involved. Create-react-app is beginner friendly and easy to use. But you have to read and follow the instructions.

Comment: It turns out I was missing       "contextIsolation: false" :) Thank you guys for your help !!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this solution ? :

```
const ipcRenderer = window.require("electron").ipcRenderer;
```

Original link : https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/7300#issuecomment-671846484

Answer (score 0):

I think your code need to trans-compile first, this is the scripts part of package.json for my node.js project, maybe useful for you:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "rm -rf dist && babel ./ -d dist --ignore 'node_modules'",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon --exec babel-node src/index.js",
    "serve": "node ./dist/index.js"
  }
```

Comment: This is what I have '  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "electron": "electron ."
  },  '

Comment: @takanoha as I said try to use babel for trans-compile before deploy your project.